# Issue with NWPathMonitor class on internet changes

Tags: ios, swift, reachability, nwpathmonitor

I'm using the **NWPathMonitor** class to check the internet changes. But I have an issue when using it. The issue is when internet is off and once it comes back, **monitor.pathUpdateHandler** is getting called/notifying twice. Where as in internet off case it is getting called only once. So, what is the mistake I'm doing here?

Below is my code snippet

```
final class NetworkMonitor {
    static let shared = NetworkMonitor()

    private let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    private let monitor: NWPathMonitor

    private(set) var isConnected = false
    private(set) var isExpensive = false
    private(set) var currentConnectionType: NWInterface.InterfaceType?

    private init() {
        monitor = NWPathMonitor()
    }

    func startMonitoring() {
        monitor.pathUpdateHandler = { [weak self] path in
            self?.isExpensive = path.isExpensive
            self?.currentConnectionType = NWInterface.InterfaceType.allCases.filter { path.usesInterfaceType($0) }.first
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .connectivityStatus, object: nil)
        }
        monitor.start(queue: queue)
    }

    func stopMonitoring() {
        monitor.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are both paths are "satisfied" in your responses?

Answer (score 0):

If you save NWPath and compare them.
You will found that paths are different.

Ex:
First is `.cellular`.
Second is `.cellular` + `.wifi`.

**Update for iOS 16.6**
`pathUpdateHandler` will fired three times.
Ex:
First is `.cellular` + `.wifi`.
Second is `.wifi`+`.cellular`.
third is `.wifi`+`.cellular`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. If he's not doing anything wrong, then be clear about that. In your "update for iOS 16.6" the second and third case you present is the exact same... that doesn't make sense.